# .Net for Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: c#, azure, google-analytics-api, azure-synapse

I am new to Azure Synapse Service. I need to know if there is any .NET sdk for Azure Synapse because my use case is that I have fronted and logical layer of .NET. I also need to use Azure Synapse for Analytics. Is there any way in Azure by which I can achieve that.

Frontend -> Logical Layer -> Azure Synapse Analytics

I know that Azure Synapse has notebook in which I can have spark C# code but is there any sdk which helps me to run my C# code on Azure Synapse apache spark cluster.

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/synapseanalytics?view=azure-dotnet

That one? It was found by a pretty simple Google query, so I'm not sure I understood your question.

Enjoy!